# Can't get Wordpress AJAX working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have been following multiple tutorials on this (including Wordpress's own) and its driving me a little crazy.

I am trying to get AJAX working on the front end in Wordpress, however it is simply not doing anything, I know the function works as I have tested this independently, your input will be really appreciated on this one. Many thanks in advance.

The code in functions.php

```
    function call_ajax()
{
    //assuming this is in a theme?
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_car_models', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax_car_models.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true);

    //loacalize the script using the same handle it was registered / enqueued with
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax_car_models', 'my_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );    
}

//make a call to call_ajax at the right time
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'call_ajax' );




add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_car_models', 'ajax_car_models' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_car_models', 'ajax_car_models' );



function ajax_car_models() {



    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 1040 );
$loop1 = new WP_Query( $args );

$code = '';

$car_make = 26;

$all_models = array();

while ( $loop1->have_posts() ) : $loop1->the_post();

$terms_make = get_the_terms( get_the_id(), 'pa_car-make' );

foreach ( $terms_make as $make ) {

    if ( $make->term_id == $car_make ) {

    $the_car_model = get_the_terms( get_the_id(), 'pa_model' );


        foreach ( $the_car_model as $the_model ) {

            if ($all_models[$the_model->name] != 'true') {

                $code .= '<br />'.$the_model->name.' ';

                $all_models[$the_model->name] = 'true';
            }
        }
    }

}


endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();

header( 'Content-type: application/json' );
echo json_encode( $code );
die();

}
```

And the jQuery itself:

```
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {


    jQuery('#car-make').change(my_js_function);

    function my_js_function() 
{
     jQuery.ajax({
     url: my_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
     dataType: 'json',   // add this line
     data: ({action : 'ajax_car_models'}),
     success: function() {
      jQuery("#feedback").html(data);
     }
     });

    }

});
```

Comment: where is 'my_ajax_script.ajaxurl' set ?

Comment: This is in the wp_localize_script function, is this incorrect?

Comment: where ... in javascript ?

Comment: that isn't accessible in JS ... they are seperate things.. PHP server side JS front side

Comment: My understanding from following the tutorials is that having this function in the functions file tells WP what PHP function to use for the AJAX response, is there a way around this?

Comment: you would have to use PHP to output that URL into your javascript while the page is being rendered

Comment: lagbox is incorrect, `localize` is the standard way to pass the ajax-url but it looks like you are missing something. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include you javascript inline you will not be able to use `localize` pass it the ajax url.

You should move your javascript into a different file and then use `wp_enqueue_script` in order to properly use ajax.

```
function call_ajax()
{
    //assuming this is in a theme?
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_car_models', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax_car_models.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true);

    //loacalize the script using the same handle it was registered / enqueued with
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax_car_models', 'my_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );    
}

//make a call to call_ajax at the right time
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'call_ajax' );
```

---

You also need to send json headers in your response function

```
header( 'Content-type: application/json' );
echo json_encode( $code );
exit();
```

---

In your ajax call you are not passing the data to your success callback

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    //...
}
```

---

You can use the network tab on the chrome developer tools to look at what requests are actually made and check the response they receive.

Comment: Thank you for your input, much appreciated, I have implemented what you said and have updated my code above, the JS is now in a separate file. The network tab in Chrome is showing a response but nothing still appearing. I tried to do a simple echo in the function and even tried just a success alert but still nothing.

Comment: I spotted that you are not passing the data to your success callback, see my edit.

When you say a success alert do you mean an `alert()` within your success callback?

If you go into the network tab, you can see the response code you are getting back, should be 200 and if you click on it then you can see the headers you are sending and the response you are getting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, its now working. I am new to AJAX and fairly new to jQuery in general, we all have to start somewhere! Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 1):

According to the PHP manual [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) needs string data to be UTF8 encoded.

Alternatively, you can try doing this instead in your functions.php...

```
$return_array = array(
   'val' => $code
);
echo json_encode($return_array);
```

Then, in your jQuery script...

```
jQuery("#feedback").html(data.val);
```

Also, try adding to your ajax request one more option...

```
 url: my_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
 dataType: 'json',   // add this line
 data: ({action : 'ajax_car_models'}),
```

Hope these help!